# Toggle on off after a li in HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an `li` in my code like below.

```
<li><a href="#">Notifications</a></li>
```

Afte the `li` I wish to have a radio toggle button in the horizontal of my li notification.

How can I do something like that? When I try to give `input type radio` it doesn't come in the horizontal line and doesn't look good.

Can somebody recommend a better solution? Here's the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xotLkj45/).

Comment: Show us what you have done so far, so that we can help you out.

Comment: hi i have a jsfiddle for your query [link](https://jsfiddle.net/subhrajyoti21/heohwzos/) basically used float style to arrange all the elements

Comment: What do you mean by 'horizontal of my li notification' ?

Comment: I want the toggle option, I am able to get it this way.

Comment: in the same line of the notification @TahaPaksu

Comment: @hunzaboy [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xotLkj45/) for you

Answer (score 0):

```html
<input type="radio" style="float:left"/><li><a href="#">Notifications</a></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have your notification like this. As you want a toggle button. it would be checkbox.

```css
li{

}
```

```html
<li><a href="#">Notifications1</a><input type="checkbox" name="hello"></li>
<li><a href="#">Notifications2</a><input type="checkbox" name="hello"></li>
<li><a href="#">Notifications3</a><input type="checkbox" name="hello"></li>
<li><a href="#">Notifications4</a><input type="checkbox" name="hello"></li>
<li><a href="#">Notifications5</a><input type="checkbox" name="hello"></li>
<li><a href="#">Notifications6</a><input type="checkbox" name="hello"></li>
<li><a href="#">Notifications7</a><input type="checkbox" name="hello"></li>
```

> You can show a fiddle or snippet of your work. it would helpful.

Comment: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xotLkj45/) for you.

I want a toggle option..

Comment: toggle means ON/OFF switch ?

Comment: Yes that toggle

Comment: [this](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_switch.asp) toggle for example. I am unable to put things together with the li

Answer (score 0):

You can use checkbox instead of radio button and then toggle `a` element.

```js
$('input').change(function() {
  $(this).next('a').toggle(!$(this).is(':checked'))
})
```

```css
li {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  width: 150px;
}
a {
  order: -1;
}
input {
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" class = "radiobtn">
    <a href="#">Notifications</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I want the toggle option YES/NO I am able to get it this way the radio button

Answer (score 0):

You can use absolute positioning. And a checkbox with label.

```css
li {
  position: relative;
}

li input[type=checkbox] {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<li>
  <label>
      <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="dummy" /> test content
  </label>
</li>
```

Comment: Toggle support added with label. But you need to use checkbox.